# What is the proper way of deleting item from a dictionary  in "for" loop (Python)?

Tags: python

I want to iterate a dictionary, examine the value and delete items that matches certain values.

Example

```
d = {1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5}   
for i in d:
  if i == 1:
    del i
```

But we know doing this is dangerous since the list is updated while it is been iterated. What is clean way of doing this in Python?

Comment: I guess you mean `d = [1,1,2,1,4,5]` (i.e. brackets, not curly braces) ?

Comment: why does this get a down vote. I am new to Python and would like to know how to do this?

Comment: Because your question asks about dictionary, but your code does not have valid syntax for a dictionary, and describes an operation that is nonsensical for a dictionary.

Comment: Even ignoring that issue, your example does nothing except iterating over the collections and (pointlessly) removing the iteration *variable*. You should review your understanding of variables and `del`. Still, the question is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `k` is your dictionary, you can do

```
k = {x:v for x,v in k.iteritems() if x != 1}
```

For 2.7+ and 3.0

For anything older, you can do

```
k = dict((x,v) for x,v in k.iteritems() if x!=1)
```

Comment: Note: Only supported in Python 3.X and 2.7+.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it to include something for older Python versions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use builtin `filter` function since it is more clear what will be done with a list. Also `filter` works with any iterable: a sequence, a container or an iterator.

Here is an example how to work with the function

```
In [2]: d = [1,1,2,1,4,5]

In [3]: filter(lambda x: (x!=1), d)
Out[3]: [2, 4, 5]
```

Instead of lambda you can pass name of other function that will be used to filter data from list.

Documentation on `filter` is available at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter

Also note, that `filter` is well-known in world of functional programming and utilizes powerful concepts so you can find it in many other languages with even different paradigm.

Comment: `filter` is not very pythonic. It would be better to use a list comprehension instead.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I could write something like this `[el for el in d if el != 1]`, but this will only work lists, not for tuples e.g. Also note, that piece of code with `filter` function will understand more programmers and it will be easier to port program to another language for example.

Comment: Why will it not work for tuples? That supports the iterator protocol too. Your second point is not really valid. Filter with a lambda is *much* slower in Python and the benefits for portability and readability are not enough to offset the bad style.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Let me see. If i will use `filter` approach it will work following way: http://codepad.org/gLKtSBT7 I don't have to change anything to filter tuples (and `filter` will return tuple instead of list). How i can achieve this using list comprehensions? I've tried and got this http://codepad.org/yi327lgN, so to filter tuple i have to modify filtering code (use smth like `tuple([x for x in d if x!=1])`)

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim also I don't care how slow lambdas in Python are until entire program performs well. And even in case of some performance issues I will use profiler first instead of trying to implement some premature optimizations.

Comment: Experience in multilanguage projects (or projects which where prototyped in functional language and ported to Python) shows that it would be better to stick with widely recognized functional programming elements (map / filter) even if PEPs (or other Python rules and styles) recommend other approaches.

Comment: Using idiomatic constructs is not premature optimisation. Your examples are also not very idiomatic since it's bad python style to look for certain "types". It's more idiomatic to look for return interfaces. If you want a `tuple`, use `tuple` on the return value.

Comment: Here are some performance numbers if you're interested. http://pastebin.com/Ma38k8RP. `filter` takes twice as much time as list comprehensions (even for such a small list). Generator expressions are faster and have better memory characteristics too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(len(d)-1,-1,-1):
  if d[j] == 1:
    del d[j]
```

Comment: This works for lists, but is ugly, nonobvious, does not generalize to non-sequences (dictionaries, sets, etc.) and is rarely needed.

Comment: Agreed. `for i in range(len(something))` is almost always a bad sign.

Answer (score 0):

While I would normally just make a new dictionary (see Noufal Ibrahim's answer), you can safely modify the existing dictionary in place by getting a list of the keys and iterating through that:

```
for k in d.keys():
    if d[k] == 1:
        del d[k]
```

Comment: Note: Works in Python 2.X, but in 3.X `d.keys()` returns a view of the dictionary and fails with `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.  Use `list(d.keys())` in 3.X.